# String comparison failing to function properly in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm all quite new to Objective-C and pointers and whatnot, so go easy on me.

Basically, i have a place in my code where i extract NSDictionaries from an NSArray based on their date key.

I check for equality by doing this:

```
if ([[dictItem valueForKey:@"Date"] isEqualToString: date])
```

Strangely though, it only becomes true for one of the many objects, namely the one with the same pointer value.

How can i explicitly and beyond any doubt compare the VALUE of two strings and NOT the pointer address?

Thanks.

Edit: Perhaps i should mention that for all the comparisons on which it fails, the date has been inserted into the dictionary from a textFields text-property, if that matters.

Comment: Whats date's type? NSString ?

Comment: Please add the logs on date and on [dictItem valueForKey:@"Date"].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work. Are you sure `[dictItem valueForKey:@"Date"]` is not nil?

Have you tried comparing without the dictionary, that is, storing one of the strings in some variable directly, just to check if that works?

Also, you might want to consider using actual `NSDate` objects. You can convert String to NSDate and vice versa with `NSDateFormatter`.

Comment: I solved it at last, marking your post as the answer here for useful information.

Comment: Turns out the problem really existed further down the line, with another failing comparison.